# Incorrect location from Telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm using standard approach for detecting user's location: keyboard button with `request_location` set to `true`.

But what I found while testing it on my mobile phone (Android), it's not always correct. When I click on the button I see how Telegram tries to get location from OS, and OS tries to use GPS.

But after all of that, if I'm inside the building, it fails to detect, because it seems like Telegram doesn't try too hard: location is sent within 2-3 seconds only.

Seems like there is no way to manually specify location while sending it. I wonder why Telegram engineers don't allow users to specify their location from the map... What kind of workaround can be applied here?

I think the only way to go for me is to ask users if location was detected correctly, and if it was not - let them try again. Any other options?

Also, can anyone confirm that it works on iOS the same way?

Answer (score 0):

As you are willing to *"Ask users if location was detected correctly..."* I automatically assume that you are not looking forward to *force* them to send their **current** location.

(If you want to force them, I suggest taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716042/how-to-find-out-whether-its-users-current-location-or-a-chosen-spot-on-map) question.)

So instead of clicking on the `location` button, (and as you say and I quote *"Letting Telegram `try` to get location"*) users can share their desired location (exactly like how they share it with other users) and the received object is the same.

Comment: That's right. I already implemented it by asking them to confirm if it's their location. I don't wanna force them, just wanted to make sure it's accurate. Sometimes it's not. I contacted Telegram support to add a feature so bot developers can have a flag to show the map with a marker before location is being sent.